# tikz: place a node relative to a boundary anchor

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to place a node relative to a boundary anchor on another node. The following code illustrates what I want to be able to do.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (A) {A}
    \node[left of=(A.160)] (b) {b};
    \draw [->] (b) -- (A.160);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

where the objective is to have the arrow from b -> A be horizontal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Basic Solution

You almost had it right already:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw] (A) {A};
        \node[left=1cm] at (A.160) (b) {b};
        \draw [->] (b) -- (A.160);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

## Alternative

Your code looks like maybe you were trying to use the `positioning` library. If that is the case, here's one way to do it using that library:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
        \node[draw] (A) {A};
        \node[left=of A.160] (b) {b};
        \draw [->] (b) -- (A.160);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Possibly Better Alternative

I'm just guessing here, but maybe what you were trying to do was simply to have multiple equally spaced „inputs“ to a single node. The problem with the angle anchors is that the angles that look good depend on the aspect ratio of the node. Here's a simple example using the `calc` library:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
        \node[draw] (A) {A};
        \coordinate (A input 1) at ($(A.north west)!0.25!(A.south west)$);
        \coordinate (A input 2) at ($(A.north west)!0.75!(A.south west)$);
        \node[left=1cm] at (A input 1) (b) {b};
        \node[below left=0.3cm] at (A input 2) (c) {c};
        \draw [->] (b) -- (A input 1);
        \draw [->] (c) |- (A input 2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: other output]

The coordinate specification `($(A.north west)!0.25!(A.south west)$)` calculates the position 25% of the way between the two given corners of `(A)`. I define coordinates to avoid having to type the number twice.